# ImportError: cannot import name for Python package

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-import

I am using Python 3.6 and I have a strange import error. My Python file contains only the line `import formic`. But when I execute the script, I get the following error:

> from formic import FileSet, Pattern, get_version
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'FileSet'

I have tried installing Formic both with and without `sudo` (yes, I know that I shouldn't use `pip` with `sudo`, but sometimes you get desperate)

I have used Formic before, but can't figure out what is going on in this situation.

If I only have `import sys`, then the script runs just fine with no errors, as expected.

Any ideas why this error occurs? Or how to fix it?

**Additional Information**

- I don't have a circular dependency, because Formic is a Python package
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9252628/623541
- I have deleted the __pycache__ folder
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/73954626/623541
- I have tried fixing PYTHONPATH
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15052360/623541

```bash
export PYTHONPATH=/home/myName/Workspace/myProject/.pyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

- I have tried installing with `sudo -H`
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52159621/623541
- I have tried installing Formic with `--no-cache-dir`
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9510610/623541
- I have purged cache with `pip cache purge`
- I have tried fixing permissions in the site-packages directory.
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16377297/623541
- I have verified that Formic is installed:

```py
$ /home/myName/Workspace/myProject/.pyenv/bin/pip3 show formic
    
Name: formic
Version: 0.9b8
Summary: An implementation of Apache Ant FileSet and Globs
Home-page: http://www.aviser.asia/formic
Author: Aviser LLP, Singapore
Author-email: formic@aviser.asia
License: GPLv3+
Location: /home/myName/Workspace/myProject/.pyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

But if I try to import Formic from the same Python, it fails:

```py
$ /home/myName/Workspace/myProject/.pyenv/bin/python

Python 3.6.9 (default, Jun 29 2022, 11:45:57) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import formic
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/myName/Workspace/myProject/.pyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/formic/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from formic import FileSet, Pattern, get_version
ImportError: cannot import name 'FileSet'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found was to upgrade to Formic2 and update the code to support it.